# Count and filter pipelines using mongodb go driver aggregate

Tags: mongodb, go, count, aggregate, bson

I have run the aggregate command as below:

```
cur, err := collection.Aggregate(
        ctx,
        []bson.M{
            bson.M{"$match": generateQueryFilter(query)},
            bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"count": "$count"}},
            bson.M{"$match": generatePaginationFilter(query)},
            bson.M{"$sort": sort},
            bson.M{"$facet": bson.M{
                "data": []bson.M{bson.M{"$limit": query.Limit}},
            }},
        },
    )
```

but I'm not sure how to get the count that I calculated from

```
bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"count": "$count"}},
```

I want the count before the 2nd $match...
Also, I am not aware of any other way I can get the data field besides using facet. Is there any other way? It looks weird that I use facet with only 1 pipeline. I have tried using $set but it seems $set and $limit can't be used in one pipeline.

Comment: It is unclear what do you want to count from your first stage. And why do you want to use a limit stage inside a facet stage ?

Comment: @ortizbje i want to count before i apply the pagination filter. No, it doesnt have to be facet, i tried $set but it doesnt work